How to get value present inside a title of a span tag
There is a report and I want to Extract a Value from it
The Value is being generated by a Component written in java script
Here is particular section code being highlighted when I do Inspect element for the below image section
Value to be Fetch
Below is the code for it and XPath
<span title="£19,649,981.19" class="right-Align">£19,650.0k</span>

XPATH: //*[@id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_HEADER_0LOAN_OUTSTANDING"]/span
Full XPATH: /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/headers/div/header[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span/span

So I am able to access the URL which I have confirmed by printing the Title of the page
But when trying to fetch value it returns empty list
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

# Setup Edge WebDriver
edge_service = EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=edge_service)

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.url_contains("dashboard"))
    desired_url = "Example.com"
    driver.get(desired_url)

    time.sleep(10)

    print("Title of the Webpage is =", driver.title)

    span_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/headers/div/header[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1/span/span')
    print(span_elements)

    span_elements1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_HEADER_0LOAN_OUTSTANDING"]/span')
    print(span_elements1)

finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

Output:

Title of the Webpage is =Overview Data
[]
[]

But I need to get Value £19,649,981.19
Full header code is presented below
You can fine the span tag also in the code from where we need data
<span title="£19,649,981.19" class="right-Align">£19,650.0k</span>


<headers class="wid-100 fl borderHide" config="'DEAL_SUMMARY_HEADER3'"><!----><!----><div class="flex wid-100 fl mt10" ng-if="vm.config.viewType != 'vertical'" ng-repeat="headers in vm.config.headers | chunkBy : ( vm.config.chunkSize || 5 )  track by $index" index="$index"> <!----><header class="wid-100 fl flex-1 border bg-color-white ml10 first-child-ml0" ng-class="::header.headersClass" ng-style="{'flex-basis': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat), 'max-width': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat)};" config="header" index="$index" ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index" style="flex-basis: 25%; max-width: 25%;"><style>.highcharts-graph{stroke-width:1px}</style><style class="darkreader darkreader--sync" media="screen"></style> <!----> <!----><div class="bg-color-white wid-100 fl" ng-if="vm.config.type === 'ADVANCE'"> <label class="wid-100 fl ptb7 plr10 bd-bottom ellipsis"> <!----> <span class="label" ng-bind-html="vm.config.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_LABEL_0LOAN_OUTSTANDING" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_LABEL_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">Loan Outstanding</span> </label> <div class="plr10 pt10 pb5 wid-100 fl"> <div class="wid-100 fl flex"> <div class="flex-2"> <!----><h1 ng-if="!vm.config.drillDownConfig" class="ellipsis fl" style="max-width:calc(100% - 20px)"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.headerData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_HEADER_0LOAN_OUTSTANDING" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span title="£19,649,981.19" class="rightAlign">£19,650.0k</span></span> </h1><!----> <!----> <span class=" ml5 mid-font" style="line-height:30px"></span> </div> <!----><div class="flex-1 fr pl10 rightAlign mt10 ellipsis" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.subHeaderData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_0LOAN_OUTSTANDING" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span title="£11,260,000" class="rightAlign">£11,260.0k</span></span> </div><!----> </div> <!----><div class="wid-100 fl rightAlign color-light small-font" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.config.subHeader.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_0LOAN_OUTSTANDING" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">Original Notional</span> </div><!----> <!----> </div> </div><!----> </header><!----><header class="wid-100 fl flex-1 border bg-color-white ml10 first-child-ml0" ng-class="::header.headersClass" ng-style="{'flex-basis': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat), 'max-width': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat)};" config="header" index="$index" ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index" style="flex-basis: 25%; max-width: 25%;"><style>.highcharts-graph{stroke-width:1px}</style><style class="darkreader darkreader--sync" media="screen"></style> <!----> <!----><div class="bg-color-white wid-100 fl" ng-if="vm.config.type === 'ADVANCE'"> <label class="wid-100 fl ptb7 plr10 bd-bottom ellipsis"> <!----> <span class="label" ng-bind-html="vm.config.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_LABEL_1NUMBER_PROP" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_LABEL_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"># Properties</span> </label> <div class="plr10 pt10 pb5 wid-100 fl"> <div class="wid-100 fl flex"> <div class="flex-2"> <!----><h1 ng-if="!vm.config.drillDownConfig" class="ellipsis fl" style="max-width:calc(100% - 20px)"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.headerData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_HEADER_1NUMBER_PROP" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span title="1" class="rightAlign">1</span></span> </h1><!----> <!----> <span class=" ml5 mid-font" style="line-height:30px"></span> </div> <!----><div class="flex-1 fr pl10 rightAlign mt10 ellipsis" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.subHeaderData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_1NUMBER_PROP" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span title="30,316" class="rightAlign">30,316 sq ft</span></span> </div><!----> </div> <!----><div class="wid-100 fl rightAlign color-light small-font" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.config.subHeader.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_1NUMBER_PROP" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">Area</span> </div><!----> <!----> </div> </div><!----> </header><!----><header class="wid-100 fl flex-1 border bg-color-white ml10 first-child-ml0" ng-class="::header.headersClass" ng-style="{'flex-basis': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat), 'max-width': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat)};" config="header" index="$index" ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index" style="flex-basis: 25%; max-width: 25%;"><style>.highcharts-graph{stroke-width:1px}</style><style class="darkreader darkreader--sync" media="screen"></style> <!----> <!----><div class="bg-color-white wid-100 fl" ng-if="vm.config.type === 'ADVANCE'"> <label class="wid-100 fl ptb7 plr10 bd-bottom ellipsis"> <!----> <span class="label" ng-bind-html="vm.config.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_LABEL_2TERM" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_LABEL_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">Term</span> </label> <div class="plr10 pt10 pb5 wid-100 fl"> <div class="wid-100 fl flex"> <div class="flex-2"> <!----><h1 ng-if="!vm.config.drillDownConfig" class="ellipsis fl" style="max-width:calc(100% - 20px)"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.headerData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_HEADER_2TERM" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span title="0.249" class="rightAlign">0.2yrs.</span></span> </h1><!----> <!----> <span class=" ml5 mid-font" style="line-height:30px"></span> </div> <!----><div class="flex-1 fr pl10 rightAlign mt10 ellipsis" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.subHeaderData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_2TERM" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span title="3" class="rightAlign">3.0yrs.</span></span> </div><!----> </div> <!----><div class="wid-100 fl rightAlign color-light small-font" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.config.subHeader.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_2TERM" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">vs. Original Term</span> </div><!----> <!----> </div> </div><!----> </header><!----><header class="wid-100 fl flex-1 border bg-color-white ml10 first-child-ml0" ng-class="::header.headersClass" ng-style="{'flex-basis': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat), 'max-width': (1/headers.length | formatter : vm.defaultFormat)};" config="header" index="$index" ng-repeat="header in headers track by $index" style="flex-basis: 25%; max-width: 25%;"><style>.highcharts-graph{stroke-width:1px}</style><style class="darkreader darkreader--sync" media="screen"></style> <!----> <!----><div class="bg-color-white wid-100 fl" ng-if="vm.config.type === 'ADVANCE'"> <label class="wid-100 fl ptb7 plr10 bd-bottom ellipsis"> <!----> <span class="label" ng-bind-html="vm.config.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_LABEL_3TEST_STATUS" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_LABEL_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">Test Status</span> </label> <div class="plr10 pt10 pb5 wid-100 fl"> <div class="wid-100 fl flex"> <div class="flex-2"> <!----><h1 ng-if="!vm.config.drillDownConfig" class="ellipsis fl" style="max-width:calc(100% - 20px)"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.headerData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_HEADER_3TEST_STATUS" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span class="leftAlign" title="Pass">Pass</span></span> </h1><!----> <!----> <span class=" ml5 mid-font" style="line-height:30px"></span> </div> <!----><div class="flex-1 fr pl10 rightAlign mt10 ellipsis" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.subHeaderData" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_3TEST_STATUS" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUB_HEADER_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])"><span class="leftAlign" title="Pass">Pass</span></span> </div><!----> </div> <!----><div class="wid-100 fl rightAlign color-light small-font" ng-if="vm.config.subHeader"> <!----> <span ng-bind-html="vm.config.subHeader.name" id="HEADER_HEADER_3_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_3TEST_STATUS" ng-dblclick="vm.isCitationEnabled &amp;&amp; vm.rootScope.$broadcast('openCitationBox', $event, 'HEADER', vm.citationList[ 'HEADER_' + vm.config.view.key + '_ADVANCE_SUBHEADER_NAME_' + vm.index + vm.config.key ])">vs. Previous Period</span> </div><!----> <!----> </div> </div><!----> </header><!----> </div><!----><!----> <!----> </headers>

NOTE: This webpage gets Value from component that are written over Javascript
DEAL_SUMMARY_HEADER3 is the component name from where the value is getting fetched

Probably your xpath query is wrong. Post the html so we can try to find de error

Please share the URL if the website is public. If not, you need to share a little bit more of HTML around that <span> element.

Don't use sleep(). It may work for you but it's not robust and even if it does work it probably introduces an unnecessary delay. Better to use selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait. Also, rather than XPATH (which can be slow) use a CSS selector which, in this case, would be "span.right-Align". Of course, that might reveal multiple span tags but without seeing more of the HTML it's hard to say how you could isolate what you're looking for

@Shawn I have added the whole code for the Header tag let me know what I am missing

@AlberiDePaula Xpath is correct I have provide the full HTML code for the header let me know if you found something
